# How to display the full name of day in datePickerUI?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

by default, the datePicker plugin is displaying the short name of day (Su, Mo, Tu, We, Th, Fr, Sa) (dayNamesMin)

I would to display the full name (Sunday....) (dayNames).

How to do it ?

I try it, but it doesn't work :

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker("option", "dayNames");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This should work:](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker#option-dayNamesMin)

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    dayNamesMin: ['Sunday', 'Monday', ...]
});
```

Comment: Yes, I think to do it, but we can not to use dayNames by default ?